# jQuery selector: Select multiple ID and get their values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a way to extract a part of an ID and use it in my script.

My HTML:

```
<div id="item1"></div>
<div id="item2"></div>
<div id="item3"></div>
<div id="item4"></div>
<div id="item5"></div>
```

My jQuery:

```
$('#item(1|2|3|4|5)').mouseout(function(event) {

    //Get the number of the item (1,2,3,4,5)
    item_number = ???

    alert(item_number);


    }
```

How can achieve this using jQuery?

Comment: Don't do that. Those items should be `<div class="item" data-id="1"></div> <div class="item" data-id="2"></div> ...etc...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Additionally to what VisioN said. I would like to encourage you to use classes for this purpose:

```
<div class="item" id="item1"></div>
<div class="item" id="item2"></div>
<div class="item" id="item3"></div>
<div class="item" id="item4"></div>
<div class="item" id="item5"></div>
```

And

```
$(".item").mouseout(...)
```

Comment: +1 ... and while you are at it, I would also add a `data-id` to keep track of the integer alone, so you don't have to parse the `id` to get to it.

Comment: So I get the element using the class and then I use: $(this).attr('data-id')? Is that it?

Comment: Yes, that's how I would do it.

Comment: Thanks Steve. Let say I use a class and a data-id (no id). Afterward, How can I edit an element if use class+data-id only? What kind of selector should I use?

Comment: I am not suggesting you drop the `id` part... still use `id` for a unique identifier of the element.  Just don't use it to extract an integer value.

Comment: @JohnS - When reading `data-attributes` that are part of the HTML, I suggest you always use `attr('data-xxx')` and not `data('xxx')`. `data()` does some type conversion for you that you may or may not want, while `attr()` always gives you the string back (and you can do the conversion you want then).  Of course, if you store and retrieve data dynamically, ALWAYS use `data()`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [*starts with selector*](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$("[id^='item']").mouseout(function(e) {
    var item_number = this.id.replace("item", "");
    alert(item_number);
});
```

Comment: Yep, it does the work, but this selector is slow. You may prefer adding a classname in your templates instead, if you can.

Comment: +1 - for a normal webpage that does'nt have 5000 elements to search thru, this will do just fine. It only attaches the event once.

Comment: @adeneo Why is there only one event attached? Or do you mean the attaching only happens once during the page's life?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do that is here:

```
$('div').mouseout(function() {
    var this_id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(this_id);
});
```

If you want to make sure not all divs get alerted, give all of those divs a class and use this instead:

```
$('.myClass').mouseout(function() {
    var this_id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(this_id);
});
```